# Order independent transparency and mixed opaque and translucent object hierarchies

Tags: three.js

We use three.js as the foundation of our WebGL engine and up until now, we only used traditional alpha blending with back-to-front sorting (which we customized a little to match the desired behavior) in our projects.

**Goal:** Now our goal is to incorporate the order-independent transparency algorithm proposed by McGuire and Bavoil in [this](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjwzaiw9bjOAhWIVBQKHXJXBGYQFggsMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjcgt.org%2Fpublished%2F0002%2F02%2F09%2Fpaper.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHyMRY_wWI3EP0yAVSV03zIaprEEw) paper trying to rid ourselves of the 
usual problems with sorting and conventional alpha blending in complex scenes.  I got it working without much hassle in a small, three.js based prototype.

**Problem:** The problem we have in the WebGL engine is that we're dealing with object hierarchies consisting of both opaque and translucent objects which are currently added to the same scene so three.js will handle transform updates. This, however, is a problem, since for the above algorithm to work, we need to render to one or more FBOs (the latter due to the lack of support for MRTs in three.js r79) to calculate accumulation and revealage and finally blend the result with the front buffer to which opaque objects have been previously rendered and in fact, this is what I do in my working prototype.

I am aware that three.js already does separate passes for both types of objects but I'm not aware of any way to influence to which render target three.js renders (`render(.., .., rt,..)` is not applicable) and how to modify other pipeline state I need. If a mixed hierarchy is added to a single scene, I have no idea how to tell three.js where my fragments are supposed to end up and in addition, I need to reuse the depth buffer from the opaque pass during the transparent pass with depth testing enabled but depth writes disabled.

**Solution A**: Now, the first obvious answer would be to simply setup two scenes and render opaque and translucent objects separately, choosing the render targets as we please and finally do our compositing as needed.

This would be fine except we would have to do or at least trigger all transformation calculations manually to achieve correct hierarchical behavior. So far, doing this seems to be the most feasible.

**Solution B**: We could render the scene twice and set all opaque and transparent materials `visible` flag to `false` depending on which pass were currently doing.

This is a variant of **Solution A**, but with a single scene instead of two scenes. This would spare us the manual transformation calculations but we would have to alter materials for all objects per pass - not my favorite, but definitely worth thinking about.

**Solution C**: Patch three.js as to allow for more control of the rendering process.

The most simple approach here would be to tell the renderer which objects to render when `render()` is called or to introduce something like `renderOpaque()` and `renderTransparent()`.

Another way would be to somehow define the concept of a render pass and then render based on the information for that pass (e.g. which objects, which render target, how the pipeline is configured and so on).

Is someone aware of other, readily accessible approaches? Am I missing something or am I thinking way too complicated here?

Comment: C, I attached something like "onWillRender" in WebGLRenderer per object. You could manually call renderer.setRenderTarget before the call.

Comment: I think you're missing nothing ... am currently implementing the same, though without the object hierarchy which is a problem for you.  Am rendering twice - once for opaque, and another for transparent - one scene for each.  I'll have to swap meshes from one scene to another as the user says "this one is [not] transparent"

Am hoping http://edankwan.com/tests/threejs-multi-render-target/webgl_mrt.html will help me around the MRT issue

Comment: Alas, NOT YET ... https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9965